# Detect different kinds of circles and ovals on the image using OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, feature-detection

I need to detect the different shapes on the image such as ellipses and circles with a dashed-border.

Using OpenCV causes some troubles, for e.g. openCV detects not a contour but an amount of small separated lines(contours).
In case of ellipse with a "dashed-border" I need it to be as single contour, not a separated objects.

What would you suggest to solve this problem?

I also need to recognize the ellipses(or circles) with solid border and ellipses(circles) with a dashed-border

**Ellipse with solid border**

[image]

**Ellipse with dashed border:**

[image]

Comment: Attach a sample image and current output with your question to get a clearer context.

Comment: can't attach as images, so I've put them on my GoogleDrive
link is attached above

Comment: But where is the image with dashed borders?

Comment: I don't know what had happen, but now it is attached as link
I am pretty new here, so some features are terrifying=)
Is it OK now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) should not have any troubles with either dashed or solid borders, or a mix thereof. I have used it to detect dashed lines in one of my project and ellipses should not be much harder.

OpenCV by default only implements the Hough transform for [circles](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghcircles) and [straight lines](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghlines) but there is a [blog entry](http://m.blog.csdn.net/article/details?id=17217451) with code on how to adapt it for elliptical shapes.

Comment: Cool - I could nor remember the transform name, but I was right on track as I was just saying that "OpenCV should include the needed transform, but it should require some tuning to work for you"

Comment: the main problem is that Hough transform detects all oval shapes on the image- doesn't matter are they solid or dashed. But for me the line-type has main value in case of detecting ellipses and circles

Comment: Dead link :/ All hail to the SO rules !

Comment: fixed the dead link :)

Answer (score 0):

The better idea there is to use an specific transform to detect circle and ellipses rather than a general "find contour" call.

I am not enough acquainted with OpenCV to know if there this sort of detection is built in there - it should be.

An internet search for the more generic "image ellipse detection" shows it is not a settled matter - unlike square and rectangle detection, so whatever OpenCV already contains will have to be tunned up. 
(The basic idea is that the underlying algorithm creates a new n-dimensional space where every possible paramterized ellipse for the target image could be represented  (with, for example, an axis for each x and y center coordinates, w and h radii, and one for  rotation), and fill in hits in this matrix according to the pixels contrast in the target image).- Sebastian's answer put the correct name for this approach I could not recall: "Hough transform", and provides the needed links on how it works, and how to extend it on OpenCV.